# TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'epochs'

Tags: neural-network

i'm trying to use NeuralProphet, but get an error with epochs.
my code is:

```
m = NeuralProphet()
m.fit(price, freq = "M", epochs = 1000)
```

i get: TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'epochs'.
Anyone know what the problem could be? Tried to follow a tutorial that wrote it like this.

Comment: if you check this [workaround](https://gist.github.com/e-alizadeh/6a4da63517f49227d33e6b3ee3825d21#file-neuralprophet_instantiation_hyperparameters-py) based on this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/neural-prophet-a-time-series-modeling-library-based-on-neural-networks-dd02dc8d868d) you can find the right arguments.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the function you are calling does not actually take the argument you provide. In this case the "fit" function you are calling does not have "epochs" as its arguments. After having looked into the NeuralProphet code , turns out that it should be something like this :

```
m = NeuralProphet(epochs = 1000)   
m.fit(price, freq = "M")
```

Comment: Thank you! that worked for the issue i got, but i now got a message that "torch" has no attribute "maximum". Is this an issue within NeuralProphet, or something i can fix easily in anaconda with the packages?

Comment: it is with Torch, you need to share code snippet for better understanding of the problem